# How to ignore the specific failed unit test result in Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have some unit tests under `Integration.java`. I want Maven to ignore the test results of this class as they fail rarely (due to external server maintenance). But I don't want to ignore them from running as I need them for code coverage.

I've tried this configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>IntegrationTest.java</include>
        </includes>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This seems to be working by ignoring the failed tests. But the problem with the above configuration is, it is ignoring the failed tests at other classes as well.

I want all the tests under `Integration.java` needs to be executed but It shouldn't have any impact on the build to determine success/failure.
But, the build should fail if any test cases fail under any other Test classes other than `Integration.java`

Comment: Using JUnit, you could use an assumption in the `@BeforeAll` method to validate the server connectivity and conditionally execute the tests. If the server is not available, the tests will not be executed.

Comment: The first thing is that integration tests should be handled by maven failsafe plugin and not by maven surefire plugin... The maven failsafe plugin has a goal `verify` on the other hand If tests failing fix the test until the work otherwise they are useless.

Comment: @khmarbaise I wasn't aware of the maven-failsafe-plugin, This might help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) has mentioned, It needs to be handled by `maven-failsafe` not `surefire plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>*IntegrationTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>failsafe-integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

By using `maven-failsafe-plugin` I made sure the test cases run and for the good code coverage and the build will not fail even if the upstream is down.

Answer (score 0):

**`Surefire`** by default includes all test classes whose name starts with Test/ends with Test/Tests/TestCase.

You can use excludes and includes parameters as per your need :

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.21.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>DataTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <includes>
            <include>DataCheck.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Build becoming success even if the test case failing at the other classes Ex: DataCheck.java

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted ?

Comment: I want all the tests under DataTest.java needs to be executed but It shouldn't have any impact on the build to determine success/failure. But, the build should fail if any test cases fail under DataCheck.java or any other Test classes other than DataTest.java